# OptimisticConcurrencyException does not exist in System.Data

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-6

I have installed EntityFramework 6 for my project. Now I want to use OptimisticConcurrencyException from System.Data but Visual Studio 2012 tells that it's not there. Where can I find it?

Comment: Do you have a reference to System.Data.Entity.dll?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. I found the answer. System.Data is deprecated and System.Data.Entity.Core should be used instead.